# Get the output type from a function

Tags: scala, types

Suppose I have the function:

```
def f(x:Long) = (x,x)
```

which signature is:

```
f: (x: Long)(Long, Long)
```

I need to get this value:

```
(object scala.Long,object scala.Long)
```

which can be built by hand as:

```
val t = (Long, Long)
```

Is there a way to do it programmatically?

Comment: As of now... this question make no sense... Can you try rewriting it in some different words...?

Comment: By the way `object scala.Long` is not the same as the type `Long`.

Comment: Do you want runtime reflection, or compile-time reflection (macros)?

Comment: I'd prefer to use compile-time reflection. @SarveshKumarSingh thanks for replying, What is not clear that I can improve?

Comment: `I need to get from this value: (object scala.Long,object scala.Long) which can build by hand as:`, both these phrases have no meaning at all. And this makes the whole question unclear.

Comment: I have a similar question with an example of why I would like to use it, which I asked here [how to determine the output type of a function type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558172/how-to-determine-the-output-type-of-a-function-type)