# How to determine the output type of a function (type)?

Tags: scala, types

We're using an IO Monad which looks like this:

```
sealed trait IOCompnent {

  def writer: AbstractWriter
  def reader: AbstractReader

  trait AbstractWriter {
    def writeFile(parentFolder: String, fileName: String)(f: Writer => Unit): Try[Unit]
  }

  trait AbstractReader {
    def readFile(filePath: String, fileName: String)(f: Reader => String): Try[String]
  }
}
```

Since we also have a similar component which uses `InputStream`/`OutputStream`, I would like to create a generic type for this by extracting the `Writer => Unit` and `Reader => String` into a type (because the result of the `InputStream` is `Array[Byte]` instead of `String`).

The only problem is, is that the `readFile` method returns a `Try` of the result of the read function, so if I define the `readFile` function as follows (only the read part of the `IOComponent`), how to determine the type of the `Try`?

```
sealed trait ReadComponent[READER] {

  def reader: AbstractReader

  trait AbstractReader {
    def readFile(filePath: String, fileName: String)(f: READER): Try[???]
  }
}
```

Comment: What about `def readFile[T](filePath: String, fileName: String)(f: READER): Try[T]` 
?

Maybe you could event have a `READER[T]` ?

Or  f : Reader => T as :
`def readFile(filePath: String, fileName: String)(f: READER => T): Try[T]`

Comment: I would go further and make READER generic, but don't use it on the trait level because it only changes on the def level: def readFile[READER[T]](filePath: String, fileName: String)(f: READER[T]): Try[T]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favorite option is 
`def readFile[T](filePath: String, fileName: String)(f: READER => T): Try[T]`

Let f decide of is output type.